# String Clean Up

Tags: python, string

I am trying to strip newline from a very very long Python string but it seems not to be working. Here is a toy example:

```
a = '''a,
b,
c,
d'''

a.strip()
```

And this is what I am getting:

```
'a,\nb,\nc,\nd'
```

I am not sure why I have the `\n` after using strip. I also tried rstrip and lstrip and got the same output

Comment: `str.{l,r,}strip` removes the characters **from the start and end**, not in-between.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is unambiguous. "...  with the leading and trailing characters removed". Not central characters

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.8/bin/python3

import re

a = '''a,
b,
c,
d'''

print(a.split('\n'))
print(re.sub('\n', '', a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the `\n` with `''`:

```
a = a.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
```